# condition-case-unless-debug code study

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros

```
(defmacro condition-case-unless-debug (var bodyform &rest handlers)
  (let ((bodysym (make-symbol "body")))
    `(let ((,bodysym (lambda () ,bodyform)))
       (if debug-on-error
           (funcall ,bodysym)
         (condition-case ,var
             (funcall ,bodysym)
           ,@handlers)))))
```

I am trying to deep-dive into this macro definition and I have many questions:

1. This macro uses nested let blocks instead of a single let block? And doesnt the inner let block's `bodysym` variable always override the outer `bodysym` variable?
2. How is `condition-case-unless-debug` different from `condition-case`? Sorry folks, the elisp doc is not clear enough.
3. `@handlers` ---> what does `@` symbol before a variable name stand for?

Comment: See **Paul Graham's book** (free) [***On Lisp***](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html), chapters 7-16. You need not read all of that, however, to get the point about the question you ask.

Comment: This question would have been better broken up into multiple questions to allow for clear answers: The first and third questions are regarding backquote expansion (and unique symbols).  The 2nd question is regarding the differences between two functions.  Leaving open since Gilles did address all the points one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `let` is evaluated during the expansion of the macro; it binds the symbol `bodysym`. The inner let is evaluated when the resulting code is executed; it binds a symbol whose name is `body`.

Here is a simpler, mostly equivalent macro, which simply uses the symbol `body`:

```
(defmacro condition-case-unless-debug (var bodyform &rest handlers)
  `(let ((body (lambda () ,bodyform)))
     (if debug-on-error
         (funcall body)
       (condition-case ,var
           (funcall body)
         ,@handlers))))
```

The problem with this simpler macro is that the code it expands to uses the symbol `body`. This interferes with the use of `body` as a variable name in the place where it is used. Instead of `body`, the macro could use a symbol like `condition-case-unless-debug/body` which isn't used anywhere else, but even that would fail if the macro is used multiple times, one nested in the other. Hence the macro uses [`make-symbol`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html#index-make_002dsymbol-497) to create a different symbol each time it is expanded. Creating fresh symbols is a common concern when writing macros that expand to code that uses temporary variables.

The difference between this macro and a plain `condition-case` should be easy to see from the simplified version above: the resulting code checks the variable `debug-on-error`, and if an error occurs, instead of applying the error handlers, the code lets the debugger catch the error. This can be useful while debugging error handling, but you wouldn't use it in production code.

`,@` in front of a variable name is a way to expand a variable under [backquotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote), like `,` except that it treats the value of the variable as a list and *splices* it. Thus in `(condition-case ,var (funcall body) ,@handlers)` the variable `handlers` should contain a list of handlers; this is equivalent to `(append (list 'condition-case var '(funcall body) ) handlers)`.